# How to call the commented section from the script file on console

Tags: python, console

So I have written my first python script (test.py) and now I want to call the docstring for the function test1 on the console but no luck

My script:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
def test1 (a , b ):
    """
    Learning Python to make a better world
    This is my first program
    """
    c = a+b
    print (c)

test1(1,2)
print (test1.__doc__)
```

But when I import the script on console this is what I get

```
C:\Python34\python.exe 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]
import test
print(test1.__doc__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test1' is not defined
print(test.test1.__doc__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test1'
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here , must be something very basic.

Comment: you can try `from test import test1` instead of `import test` if python script file is named `test.py`

Comment: You have to debug further. Try calling test.__dict__ to see the contents of test. Are you calling the wrong file? Check if `test.py` is in the directory that your python installation is in. You might be calling the wrong file. If you installed for all users, this directory is usually C:/Python34 because you are using Python 3.4. Otherwise, search your computer for the Python34 folder.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. I tried both options and here is the result
from test import test1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'test1'
from test.py import test1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\PC\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'test.py'

Comment: @PythonGuy Doesnt look like my test script :(
import test
test.__dict__
{'__package__': 'test', '__cached__': 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\test\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-34.pyc', '__file__': 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\test\\__init__.py', '__path__': ['C:\\Python34\\lib\\test'], '__spec__': ModuleSpec(name='test', loader=<_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at

Comment: @Fenomatik Ahh, I see! That helped! You have made `test.py` a package. That's why it says `'package':'test'`. When you import the test *package*, it executes the `__init__.py` only. Make `test.py` a single python script in the Python34 directory. If this isn't right, you might have another test.py in your Lib directory. Try renaming the python file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python3 has a `test` module which is for internal use only. Refer: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/test.html

So if you saved your script into a file called `test.py`, the only way to import that script is when you run python console on the same directory as your test.py script. Just change your filename to `mytest.py` and do `import mytest` and `print(mytest.test1.__doc__)` to avoid issues.

Comment: Now I have changed the name to firstscript.py , but now when i try to import it i get an error 
import firstscript
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\PC\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.4.0.201510052309\pysrc\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: No module named 'firstscript'

path to my script file is /test/firstscript.py , is there a special way to call script in different location ?

Comment: You can execute the script and let it print stuff. If you want to open console first, you either 1. have be on the same directory as the script or 2. make folder containing the script a package by creating an empty `__init__.py` inside test folder and open console in the parent of the test folder or 3. make test folder a package as in step 2 and set the PYTHONPATH to the folder containing your test folder and you can import your package from anywhere you are. Just keep in mind of the issues of having a package or module called 'test'. You rather ask another question about setting up paths

Comment: I am trying to change the path in the console but this aint working
os.chdir("C:\Users\PC\workspace\myscript")
  File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: I am using Eclipse with PyDev , so when i create a new project , i pick the option where is says "Add project directory to the PYTHONPATH" then why I am not even able to import the module anyhow ?

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly imported some `test` module that lives inside the real python installed by other Python packages, and not your `test.py`.  In this simple case, you need to run `python` from the same directory as `test.py` and verify that the `test` module is actually imported, if imported relatively it should look like this:

```
>>> import test
>>> print(test)
<module 'test' from 'test.pyc'>
```

Otherwise it would show something like this:

```
>>> import test
>>> print(test)
<module 'test' from '/usr/lib/python3.4/test/__init__.py'>
```

Best practice is that don't name your casual modules with test.py, reserve that for unit/functional tests.